# Countifs formula: count if matches month, year and another criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure this is quite a simple formula to some, however I'm struggling to get this right.

The data I have is:

```
     A              C             D
Location 1        Name       10/10/2019 
Location 2        Name       01/10/2019  
Location 1        Name       10/08/2020
Location 1        Name       12/10/2019
. . .
```

I am trying to count how many are in a location in each month of the year. (Eg above the count for Location 1 in Oct 19 is **2**)

I have managed to get some aspects working, but I cannot get it working together.

eg, this works: `=COUNTIFS('sheet1'!D5:D298,">"&30/10/2020)` 
works however `=COUNTIFS('sheet1'!D5:D298,"<"&30/10/2020)` does not.

I also cannot get it working with the multiple criteria. ( `=COUNTIFS('Counter Balance'!D5:D298,">"&30/10/2020, 'Counter Balance'!A5:A110, "Location 1")`

I'm clearly doing something obvious wrong but I just can't see it!

Hopefully that makes sense, any advice would be much appreciate,
thank you!

Comment: For a `COUNTIFS` with multiple criteria, each criteria range must have the same number of rows and columns.

Comment: Oh thank you very much - I didn't know this!

Comment: And working with dates is also quite tricky. If you want to hard code a date in a formula, I would recommend to use the function `DATEVALUE`, so you are sure to have a valid date for your testing.

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,A9,$C$2:$C$5,">="&DATE(C9,B9,1),$C$2:$C$5,"<"&DATE(C9,B9+1,1))
```

[image]

qty results to 2, as you may expect

Answer (score 1):

The `COUNTIFS` function needs to have a bit of uniformity in the formula to work.

Microsoft references it [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

> Important: Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

While not necessary, I would recommend using `DATE` functions, cell references, named ranges, or some other form of control for comparing dates in formulas. Excel treats a date as an integer internally. Combine that with differences in language localization and its pretty easy for the dates in date format to not mean what you want them to mean.

To try to correct your formula, I would recommend this:

```
=COUNTIFS('Counter Balance'!D5:D298,">"&DATE(2020,10,30), 'Counter Balance'!A5:A298, "Location 1")
```